# Why is Netbeans Overwriting my Code?

Tags: java, netbeans, editor, netbeans-7

I am having a slight problem.  I believe that my Netbeans is set to overwrite, so when ever I type something, it deletes whats in front of it.  The editor cursor has also changed, from the usual vertical line, to a solid black block.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try pressing the <kbd>Insert</kbd> button on your keyboard.
You can confirm this by looking the lower right hand corner a 'OVR' means you are in Overwrite mode, whereas 'INS' means you're in insert mode(the mode you want to be in).

[image: Overwrite mode]
vs.
[image: Insert mode]

See [Wikipedia docs on Insert Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overwrite), also see highlighted button shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Press the insert key on your keyboard.